# How to retrieve result set from MySQL case query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking for an answer to this all afternoon so far and cannot come up with anything yet. 
I have the following MySQL PDO query:

```
$q = "select recip_id,

sum(case when msg_read = '0' AND msg_deleted = '0' then 1 else 0 end) uu,
sum(case when msg_read = '0' AND msg_deleted = '1' then 1 else 0 end) ud,
sum(case when msg_read = '1' AND msg_deleted = '0' then 1 else 0 end) ru,
sum(case when msg_read = '1' AND msg_deleted = '1' then 1 else 0 end) rd,
count(*) as total

from messages where recip_id = :d GROUP BY recip_id WITH ROLLUP";`
```

which, when I use recip_id = 18  for an example in PHPMyAdmin gives me the following table:

[image: mysql results table]

I have tried several ways to fetch the resulting row in php so that I can use the values for another task, to no avail. I've tried this:

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare($q);
$row = $stmt->execute(array(":id" => $id));  
$total = $row['total'];
$uu = $row['uu'];
$ud = $row['ud']; 
$ru = $row['ru'];
$rd = $row['rd'];
echo "Recipient id: $id, Total: $total, UU: $uu, UD: $ud, RU: $ru, RD: $rd";
```

And this:

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare($q);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$msgcount = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {   
        $total = $row->total;
    $uu = $row->uu;
    $ud = $row->ud; 
    $ru = $row->ru;
    $rd = $row->rd;
     }
    echo "Recipient id: $id, Total: $total, UU: $uu, UD: $ud, RU: $ru, RD: $rd";
```

and this too:

```
    $msgcount = array();
    $stmt = $dbo->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {   
    array_push($msgcount, array($row['uu'], $row['uu'], $row['ud'], $row['ru'], $row['rd'])); 
}
    echo $msgcount[];
```

I cannot retrieve the values using my PHP script from the MySQL result set. I've tried serialize() on the rows and whole result set, I've tried to use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC and also unspecified fetch() and fetchAll(). *'ve used different combos and just get an empty result set or *I can't find an answer anywhere either. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first attempt you forget to `$stmt->fetch`, and in the last two you forget `$stmt->execute`. Try this:

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare($q);
if ( ! $stmt->execute(array(":id" => $id)) ) die("error");  // returns true or false
$row = $stmt->fetch();                                      // add this line!
$total = $row['total'];
$uu = $row['uu'];
$ud = $row['ud']; 
$ru = $row['ru'];
$rd = $row['rd'];
echo "Recipient id: $id, Total: $total, UU: $uu, UD: $ud, RU: $ru, RD: $rd";
```

Comment: Thanks @Kenney, that works perfectly. Stupid mistakes to make really!

Comment: You're welcome! And don't beat yourself up over it - part of learning is making mistakes :)